# How a Subtask can Create a Subtask

Tags: workflow, jira, parent, jql

I know how to automatically create subtasks when the Parent Status changes, But how do I automatically create subtasks when another subtask closes (Without changing the parent status)?

Comment: I Found that the [Bob Swift Plugin "Create on Transition"](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CSOT/Create+on+Transition+for+JIRA)﻿ Works very well. It lets you assign a post function to a subtask workflow and that post function lets you create another subtask off of the parent when the original subtask is transitioned. It solved my issue perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create a custom listener using Script Runner. The code can be something like that:

```
class ExampleListener extends AbstractIssueEventListener {
    Category log = Category.getInstance(ExampleListener.class)

    @Override
    void workflowEvent(IssueEvent event) {
        log.debug "Event: ${event.getEventTypeId()} fired for ${event.issue} and caught by ExampleListener"
    }
}
```

You can find that section on the administration area, it is called "Script Listeners". In this way you can catch the event and do what you need after some checks (is a subtask, status ....).
You can retrieve everything you need from the event object.

https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Listeners

Comment: That would probably work very well if I only had a few subtasks. However, since I have roughly 40-50 subtasks throughout our process, AND Since Script Runners listeners are super disorganized (unlabeled) It can get very confusing and hard to go back and find the right listener to edit when I've got that many subtasks. But in most situations this would be perfect! Thank you!